# Regular and non regular parametrizations

Tags: differential-geometry

A proposition from Pressley’s book says, ‘Any reparameterization of a regular curve is regular’ and then gives an example to show that a curve can have both regular and non regular reparameterizations. How does one reconcile this? Does this mean that finding a parameterization is not the same as doing a reparameterization? My question is for some given curve suppose we find two parameterizations $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$, is there always a reparameterization map between these two?
He gives two parameterizations for parabola, $(t,t^2)$ and $(t^3,t^6)$. Is there a reparameterization map between these? If so, doesn’t this contradict the proposition?

Comment: What is the meaning of "regular" in this context ?

Comment: $\gamma\dot $never vanishes

Comment: I mean $\left(\cos(t), \cos^2(t)\right)$ is not a proper parameterization, no? So there are contraints on what constitutes a "proper" parameterization.

Comment: When you say $\dot{\gamma}$ never vanishes, you're saying the reparameterization must be monotonic (either increasing or decreasing). And I don't think that's necessary, instead, the reparameterization must have the same range as whatever a "correct" parameterization has. You can have non-monotonic reparameterization, as long as they cover the entire range.

Comment: My question is that why does this example seem to contradict the proposition that ‘any reparametrization of a regular curve is regular’?

Comment: **My question is for some given curve suppose we find two parameterizations $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$, is there always a reparameterization map between these two?** Only if both parameterizations are one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not going to answer your question, but I am going to focus in on: **My question is for some given curve suppose we find two parameterizations $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$, is there always a reparameterization map between these two?**

I would argue the answer is yes if they are both monotonic (*and continuous--it doesn't need to be monotonic to be one-to-one if it's discontinous*) and no, in general. Very simple example, let's take the line $y = x$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}: x \geq 0$. An obvious parameterization is $(x, y) \mapsto (t, t)$ (obviously $t\in\mathbb{R}: t \geq 0$). What about $(x, y) \mapsto \left(t^2, t^2\right)$ where $t \in \mathbb{R}$? Surely both parameterize the original curve. *However*, there isn't a clear map between the two.

OK, so that one is easily resolved by limiting the $\left(t^2, t^2\right)$ to $t \in \mathbb{R}: t \geq 0$, but what about $(x, y) \mapsto \left(2t^3 - 9t^2 + 12t, 2t^3 - 9t^2 + 12t\right)$ where $t \in \mathbb{R}: t \geq 0$? This is *not* a one-to-one function within the domain $t \geq 0$ (it has two local extrema at $t = 1$ and $t = 2$, respectively):

[image: 3rd Degree Polynomial with two local extrema]

So while *both* parameterize the curve $y = x$, we cannot recover the non-monotonic parameterization ($2t^3 - 9t^2 + 12t$) from the monotonic one ($t$)--literally because $2t^3 - 9t^2 + 12t$ isn't one-to-one.

Comment: Oh wow, I used the exact same function in another [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1278165/how-to-know-what-kinds-of-substitution-can-we-do-in-math/1278193#1278193) (I'm not very original, I guess, roots of 1 and 2 are all I can think of, lol)